# How can I recreate this navigation bar using HTML and CSS?

Tags: html, css, navigation

```css
.header {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.nav-bar {
  background-color: var(--nav-color );
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  height: 43px;
  margin: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1.5px solid #000000;
}
.first {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 4;
  width: 106px;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
.second {
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
  left: -29px;
  z-index: 3;
  border-radius: 0 15px 15px 0;
}
.third {
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
  left: -60px;
  z-index: 2;
  border-radius: 0 15px 15px 0;
}
```

```html
<!--===== HEADER =====-->
  <header class="header">
    <!--===== NAV-BAR =====-->
    <a href=#home class="nav-bar first"><span class="nav-bar-title">Home</span></a>
    <a href=#about class="nav-bar second"><span class="nav-bar-title">About</span></a>
    <a href=#more class="nav-bar third"><span class="nav-bar-title">More</span></a>
</header>
```

[navigation bar in Realme file manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k26Jr.jpg)

I want to get triangular shaped right edges, tell me how can I recreat it.

Share if there is any template for similar looking navigation bar.

The snippet contains the HTML and CSS code of my version,

Comment: Please show us what code you have tried, what research you have already done. I'm afraid SO isn't an ab initio coding service, but we are very happy to help you debug your code. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: If you are totally stuck on creating these shapes, have a look at CSS clip-path.

Comment: Have a look on codepen if you can find some examples of breadcrumbs or menus that look visually similar to what you are trying to achieve. Perhaps something like https://codepen.io/iamglynnsmith/pen/BRGjgW could help you start up. He used a pseudo element on the right, that he rotated to make it look like an arrow. I imagine that `transform` could help you "squash" it with a `scale(0.5, 1)` to make it look more like what you would like to have. This one too: https://codepen.io/renaudtertrais/pen/nMGWqm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can make use of some [`conic-gradient()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/conic-gradient):

```css
#breadcrumb {
  display: flex;
  background: #f6ede4;
}

.item {
  padding: 1em 3em 1em 2em;
  background-image:
    conic-gradient(
      from 210deg at calc(100% - 1em) 50%,
      #f6ede4 120deg,
      transparent 120deg
    ),
    conic-gradient(
      from 210deg at 100% 50%,
      #ffffff 120deg,
      transparent 120deg
    );
}
```

```html
<div id="breadcrumb">
  <div class="item">Phone storage</div>
  <div class="item">Download</div>
  <div class="item active">Apps</div>
</div>
```

...or some [`mask`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask) on a pseudo-element:

```css
#breadcrumb {
  display: flex;
  background: #f6ede4;
}

.item {
  position: relative;
  padding: 1em 2em;
}

.item::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(100% + 1em);
  background-image:
    conic-gradient(
      from 210deg at calc(100% - 1em) 50%,
      #f6ede4 120deg,
      transparent 120deg
    ),
    conic-gradient(
      from 210deg at 100% 50%,
      #ffffff 120deg,
      transparent 120deg
    );
  -webkit-mask: conic-gradient(
    from 180deg at calc(100% - 2em) 50%,
    transparent 180deg,
    #000 180deg
  );
  mask: conic-gradient(
    from 180deg at calc(100% - 2em) 50%,
    transparent 180deg,
    #000 180deg
  );
}
```

```html
<div id="breadcrumb">
  <div class="item">Phone storage</div>
  <div class="item">Download</div>
  <div class="item active">Apps</div>
</div>
```